# How to overload [] operator to initialize an object

Tags: c++

I wanted to implement a class like std::map (just for exercise and learning purposes). I defined my std::map variant like the following one:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
class mmap
{
private:
    std::vector<DATA<Key, Value>> m_maped;
    DATA<Key, Value> m_elements;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    bool m_repeated_entity = false;

public:
    mmap() {}

    mmap(std::vector<DATA<Key, Value>> arg_mapped)
    {
        for (auto const& pair : arg_mapped)
        {
            push_back(pair.m_key, pair.m_value);
        }
    }

    void push_back(std::vector<DATA<Key, Value>> arg_mapped)
    {
        for (auto const& pair : arg_mapped)
        {
            push_back(pair.m_key, pair.m_value);
        }
    }

    void push_back(Key arg_key, Value arg_value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_mutex);

        if (std::none_of(m_maped.begin(), m_maped.end(), [&](auto& it) {return it.m_key == arg_key; }))
        {
            m_elements.m_key = arg_key;
            m_elements.m_value = arg_value;
            m_maped.push_back(m_elements);
        }
    }
}
```

}

It works fine. I can use the above class like the following one:

```
mka::container::mmap<int, std::string> g_map_single;
g_map_single.push_back(1, "Jimmy");
g_map_single.push_back(2, "Mimmy");
g_map_single.push_back(2, "Kimmy");

mka::container::mmap<int, std::string> g_map_list;
g_map_list.push_back({ {1, "Jimmy"}, {2, "Kimmy"}, {2, "Limmy"} });
```

There is no problem till here, but when I wanted to initialize my class like the following, I couldn't:

```
mka::container::mmap<int, std::string> g_map_init[{ {1, "Jimmy"}, { 2, "Kimmy" }, { 2, "Limmy" } }];
mka::container::mmap<int, std::string> g_map_equal = g_map_list;
```

The above two code failed to compile. I research and I find out I should overload = and [] operators but I don't know what is the best approach to overload them. I used the following code but all of them didn't work.

```
void operator[](Key arg_key, Value arg_value)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_mutex);

    if (std::none_of(m_maped.begin(), m_maped.end(), [&](auto& it) {return it.m_key == arg_key; }))
    {
        m_elements.m_key = arg_key;
        m_elements.m_value = arg_value;
        m_maped.push_back(m_elements);
    }
}
```

How should I fix my code?

Comment: `g_map_init[ .... ]` is an array declaration, no? `How should I fix my code?` Why not just do `g_map_init{ {stuff here } }` like a normal C++ code?

Comment: Are you going to construct `g_map_init` using `[] operator`? It won't work.

Comment: @KamilCuk It is a vector.

Comment: It's not a vector. The line is `type g_map_init[ stuff here ];`. That's how you declare an array - `int array[5];`

Comment: @vahancho Why? I see we can do the same thing for std::map.

Comment: vectors are accessed with [], but constructed with {}

Comment: @JackLilhammers So I should overload {}?

Comment: From the look of it, `mka::container::mmap<int, std::string> g_map_init{{ {1, "Jimmy"}, { 2, "Kimmy" }, { 2, "Limmy" } }};` should just work with `mmap(std::vector<DATA<Key, Value>> arg_mapped)`.

Comment: @Cayoot, I doubt you can. You can access already existing element of the container, but not construct it.

Comment: `type var[N];` just creates an array. It's not the same thing as calling type::operator[] which requires an already initialized var. Maybe take a look at [std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) and how you can use it in your constructors.

Comment: @m88 How should use that in this code? is there any example suitable with my situation?

Comment: @Cayoot There's a minimal example at the bottom of the cppreference page I linked you

Comment: No, you should just construct it in the standard way. Also, imagine if you could make it that your map behaved differently. Every other programmer reading your code would probably guess wrong the first time, and have to learn your way of doing things. That would be quite unpractical

Comment: I'd also suggest you would not name your class `mmap`. `mmap` is a Linux syscall and I would be very confused if I saw this without knowing the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is a `std::initializer_list` of Key-Value pairs submitted to the index (`[]`) operator of the `mmap` class. By default, the compiler doesn't create an overload to the index operator like that, we need to explicitly define it. It may look something like this,

```cpp
void operator[](const std::initializer_list<DATA<Key, Value>>& list)
{
    for (auto const& pair : list)
        push_back(pair.m_key, pair.m_value);
}
```

Usually the index operator is used for array indexing or to index a value in a map. Doing it like this is unusual (not meaning that its wrong). As in the comment by @KamilCuk, you can instead use `g_map_init{ {stuff here } }`. Its more readable and the `std::vector` has an overloaded constructor to get it done.